# How to print lines between 2 values using tail & head and pipe?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, pipe, tail, unix-head

For example:how can I print specific lines of a .txt file between line 5 and line 8 using only tail and head

Comment: I have no code, I just want to know how to solve this problem

Comment: Another example: there is a.txt and it have 15 lines.Print the lines between line 4 and 9 using tail and head commands.

Comment: How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Copied from [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/47407/cat-line-x-to-line-y-on-a-huge-file)

`infile.txt` contains a numerical value on each line.

```
➜   X=3
➜   Y=10
➜   < infile.txt tail -n +"$X" | head -n "$((Y - X))"
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
➜
```

Answer (score 0):

if a.txt contains lines below:

products,
apple,
banana,
carrot,
dairy,

and if you want to print lines between 1 and 5
i.e-apple,banana,carrot.you can use below command:

```
cat a.txt | head -n -5 | tail +2
```